# Laravel 5.2 Auth facade and Auth::guard($guard)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am new to Laravel. I was browsing the default authenticate middleware and I see that it is using:

```
Auth::guard($guard)->guest()
```

to check if the user is a guest.

The documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user tells that one can use:

```
Auth::check()
```

To figure out if a user is authenticated. (I image this is opposite of guest() ?

I tried changing the default code to use

```
Auth::guest()
```

and I am getting exactly the same result.

My question is, what is the difference between having *guard($guard)->* or not in this case?

A related question. Is guest() completely opposite of check() or are there circumstances where these may return same results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The authenticate middleware allows you to specify what type of auth guard you want to use. Laravel 5.2 comes with two out of the box, **'web'** and **'api'**.

The Auth facade uses the 'web' guard by default if none is specified. So for example:  `Auth::user()` is doing this by default: `Auth::guard('web')->user()`

The other auth driver out of the box called **'api'**. So for example you can call your middleware like this: `$this->middleware('auth:api');`

This will check that the user is authenticated by api_token instead of session. Then you can get an instance of the user by `Auth::guard('api')->user()` instead of `Auth::user()` which is the same as `Auth::guard('web')->user()`

You would use this if your application has an API endpoint allowed for logged in users only. then a user can make a request like yourapp.com/api-method?api_token=blahblah. Then you can use the 'api' auth guard to authenticate and grab the logged in User.

I found this tutorial pretty useful in setting it up: http://learninglaravel.net/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-52

And to answer your second question. Yes guest() is just the opposite of check(). check out laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers.php

Comment: FWIW, the learninglaravel shittily copies other posts. The original content is at https://mattstauffer.co/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no difference - if you examine the `Auth` facade than you'll see that the `Auth::guest()` is a shorthand of the `Auth::guard($guard)->guest()`. `Auth::check()` is a:

```
/**
 * Determine if the current user is authenticated.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function check()
{
    return ! is_null($this->user());
}
```

and `Auth::guest()` is a opposit of `Auth::check()`:

```
/**
 * Determine if the current user is a guest.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function guest()
{
    return ! $this->check();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is the purpose of guard($guard) here ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstable I wan to show you how Auth::guard()->guest() work.

```
/**
 * Attempt to get the guard from the local cache.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */ 

public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return isset($this->guards[$name])
                ? $this->guards[$name]
                : $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

The guard Method will Return to \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard or \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard this is two types of Interface, it will help laravel select guest() or check() method.
If you have been used Auth:check() and Auth::guest() but it only show the same Result. Maybe you were Set the attemp Method in login() like this code below

```
Auth::attempt(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password],$rememberMe,true)
```

You just need to Remove true Argument, It will Return right Value like you desire